# No funciona el if

Tags: c#, textarea

Cuando estoy por ejecutar el código, en la parte del if pregunto que si la Var1 es mayor o igual que 402.336; el caso es que cuando el resultado es mayor, por ejemplo:
Que en el programa puse un 5 cuando pedí la velocidad, la variable Var1 obtendrá el valor 579.36384; el problema en todo esto es que cuando se imprime el resultado de el método LoLogro me imprime "No logro romper su récord". En pocas palabras no logra dar la respuesta correcta cuando debe darlo, aún no sé cómo corregir el problema y llevo mucho rato probando sin éxito.

````
class Programa4
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double Tiempo;
        string respuesta;

        Console.Write("Escribe cuanto tiempo tardo en segundos: ");
        respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
        Tiempo = double.Parse(respuesta);

        Arrancon A1 = new Arrancon();

        Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Lologro());
        Console.WriteLine("Su velocidad fue de: "+A1.Velocidad(Tiempo));
    }
}

public class Arrancon
{
    double Var1;
    public double Velocidad(double Tiempo)
    {
        Var1 = ((402.336 * 2)/1000)/(Tiempo/3600);
        return Var1;
    }
    public string Lologro()
    {
        string respuesta;
        if (Var1 >= 402.336)
        {
            respuesta = "Si logro romper su record";
        }
        else
        {
            respuesta = "No logro romper su record";
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Var1 es cero cuando llamas a Lologro

Comment: `decimal Var1;`

Comment: ¿Y cómo se podría arreglar el problema? @Yussef

Answer (score 2):

Simplemete llame al método Velocidad antes del Lologro:

```
class Programa4
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double Tiempo;
string respuesta;

Console.Write("Escribe cuanto tiempo tardo en segundos: ");
respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
Tiempo = double.Parse(respuesta);

Arrancon A1 = new Arrancon();

Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________");
var time=A1.Velocidad(Tiempo);
Console.WriteLine(A1.Lologro());
Console.WriteLine("Su velocidad fue de: " +time);
Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Arrancon
{
    double Var1;
    public double Velocidad(double Tiempo)
    {
        Var1 = ((402.336 * 2)/1000)/(Tiempo/3600);
        return Var1;
    }
    public string Lologro()
    {
        string respuesta;
        if (Var1 >= 402.336)
        {
            respuesta = "Si logro romper su record";
        }
        else
        {
            respuesta = "No logro romper su record";
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
}
```

Esto porque la velocidad debe calcularse antes de llamar el método Lologro sino nunca va a dar el resultado correcto

Answer (score 1):

El pasar variables a un constructor se hace justamente para evitar este tipo de problemas. Tu clase Arranco no tiene sentido si Var1 no está seteada, por eso debe ir en el constructor.

```
class Programa4
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal Tiempo;
        string respuesta;

        Console.Write("Escribe cuanto tiempo tardo en segundos: ");
        respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
        Tiempo = Convert.ToDecimal(respuesta);
        Arrancon A1 = new Arrancon(Tiempo );

        Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Lologro());
        Console.WriteLine("Su velocidad fue de: "+A1.Velocidad);
    }
}

public class Arrancon
{

    public decimal Velocidad {get;set;}
    public Arrancon(decimal tiempo){
       Velocidad = ((402.336m * 2)/1000)/(tiempo/3600);
    }
    public string Lologro()
    {
        if (Velocidad >= 402.336m)
        {
            return "Si logro romper su record";
        }
        return "No logro romper su record";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tu error esta en que nunca usas la variable `var1`, por lo tanto nunca se validara tu condicion, la forma de solucionarlo seria mandando el dato por tu constructor:

```cs
Arrancon(double dat){
 var1=dat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Únicamente debes de llamar primero la velocidad y luego llamar el método de logro, hice una variable para el tiempo y una de la respuesta consumiendo los métodos segun el orden y finalemente agregue un ReadKey para deteter el programa ya que se cerraba de una, hice lo siguiente:

```
Arrancon A1 = new Arrancon();
double Tiempo2 = A1.Velocidad(Tiempo);
string Respuesta = A1.Lologro();

Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________");
Console.WriteLine(Respuesta);
Console.WriteLine("Su velocidad fue de: " + Tiempo2);
Console.ReadKey();
```